# How to get original file URL from a LivePhoto's video asset without saving its resource locally? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, url, phasset, phlivephoto

I've searched and found some ways where I can get the video asset/file of the LivePhoto asset. But what those methods do are as follows:

1. They somehow get the resources(PHAssetResource) for the LivePhoto asset
2. Select the specific video resource(PHAssetResource) from previously found resources.(Ex: `resource.type==PHAssetResourceTypePairedVideo`)
3. Save the resource data to a **new File**(!)
4. Get the URL for the **newly created File.**

But, what I want to know, is there any way I can get the URL for the originally stored file URL, **without** creating a new File?

[For other types of photos/videos I'm able to get the URLs of the originally stored files. The problem is with the video of the LivePhoto asset.]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to directly get the original *URL* of the file. There is no need to save the file contents in a new file. (Tested on **iOS12+**)

1. We first get the file *URL* of associated **Image** of the *LivePhoto*.

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil) { (editingInput, info) in
    if let input = editingInput, let imgUrl = input.fullSizeImageURL {
        // use imgUrl
    }
}
```

2. The **Video** file is stored in the same directory as the image file. So, we use the **Image** *URL* but with different extension to find the **Video** file of the *LivePhoto*. The video file extension is either **.mov** or **.MOV**.

```
if let videoPath = (imagePath.deletingPathExtension as NSString).appendingPathExtension("MOV") {
    let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    // check if file exist and use
    // If MOV(Uppercase) extension file doesn't exist check for mov(lowercase) extension similarly
}
```